# Clean and reset a form without leaving it with C#

Tags: c#, forms, reload, reset

Plop,

I'm currently working on a Hangman game with C#. I use a main form to the menu, then I start another form within the first form in that way :

```
Form2 game = new Form2();
game.ShowDialog();
```

So when I finish a game, I don't want to close it form, but I want to reload the whole form. Here is the way I do :

```
private void Replay(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Controls.Clear();
    this.InitializeComponent();
    Form2_Load(this, null);

}
```

This code removes all Controls then recreate them with `InitializeComponent`. I thought removing controls would clean the screen but it doesn't. Some labels and PictureBox that are removed still stay displayed.

Where am I doing this wrong ?

Comment: What does "Plop." mean? You could try adding a this.Refresh(), and see if that helps. But what you should really do is redesign your program so that setting/resetting the initial visuals is part of the program design, not an after-thought that you try to add on to an existing design.

Comment: Thank you that's exactly what I was looking for !

Plop means "Hi" if you want. :)